# Eclipse Java EE and tomcat6 server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I installed Eclipse and tomcat6 service on windows 8

i get the tomcat front page at localhost:8080 and in server tab in eclipse it says "Tomcat v6.0 at localhost Started, Syncronized" however im unable to run any of my imported projects on server.

Right click on server -> add and remove... -> There are no resources that can be added

Right click on project -> Properties -> Facets, Dynamic web module is checked

in project properties, in targeted runtimes i only get option for tomcat7
and if i click show all runtimes it will show 6.0 but it's diabled and cannot be selected.

Does this mean i have to uninstall 6 and install 7 instead or what?
all the project files are from school so i dont know about them but i dont remember anyone saying that i need to install newer version...

Trying to run on server just brings up server selection without possibility to use existing server...

Comment: What's your java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the Dynamic Web Module Version. Tomcat 6 supports upto version 2.5 if I am right. So upgrade to use a newer tomcat (By the way tomcat 6 is very old and you should use at least 8) or use an older Dynamic Web Module Version.

Comment: okey, i had some ancient eclipse with options only up to 6.0 but i installed new eclipse and tomcat 9.0 and everything is working fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had some troubles to install Eclipse with tomcat 6. The problem was that the server was not compatible with the Dynamic Web.

For that reason download a new version of the server. Just change the parameters and you will run your app. Also be sure about you have the JDK that you need installed.

> Last version of Apache Tomcat:
>   https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi